# google-api-php-client does not contain permissions method "getIdForEmail"

Tags: php

I need to use the method [getIdForEmail](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail) to manage permissions to drive files, and there is an example in the docs using the php client library with this method, however browsing the source it doesn't seem to be implemented yet.  Is there a workaround until it is added to the release, or a patch that can added (to Google_DriveService.php)?

Using the latest release of the [php client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) version 0.6.6.

EDIT:
A not-so convenient workaround to this problem is to grab the permission id the first time the user connects and save it to your app's database for later use.  Although it would be cleaner for alot of apps to be able to trade an email address for a permission id, regardless of whether the user is authenticated or not.

EDIT2: checked version 0.6.7 still no getIdForEmail function.

Answer (score 0):

The function does exist here

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php?r=577

So in your DriveService.php file add

```
/**
 * Returns the permission ID for an email address. (permissions.getIdForEmail)
 *
 * @param string $email The email address for which to return a permission ID
 * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
 * @return Google_PermissionId
 */
public function getIdForEmail($email, $optParams = array()) {
  $params = array('email' => $email);
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  $data = $this->__call('getIdForEmail', array($params));
  if ($this->useObjects()) {
    return new Google_PermissionId($data);
  } else {
    return $data;
  }
}
```

in the Google_PermissionsServiceResource class

then replace the line that starts with $this->permissions

with

```
$this->permissions = new Google_PermissionsServiceResource($this, $this->serviceName, 'permissions', json_decode('{"methods": {"delete": {"id": "drive.permissions.delete", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions/{permissionId}", "httpMethod": "DELETE", "parameters": {"fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "permissionId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}, "get": {"id": "drive.permissions.get", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions/{permissionId}", "httpMethod": "GET", "parameters": {"fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "permissionId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}}, "response": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]}, "getIdForEmail": {"id": "drive.permissions.getIdForEmail", "path": "permissionIds/{email}", "httpMethod": "GET", "parameters": {"email": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}}, "response": {"$ref": "PermissionId"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]}, "insert": {"id": "drive.permissions.insert", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions", "httpMethod": "POST", "parameters": {"emailMessage": {"type": "string", "location": "query"}, "fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "sendNotificationEmails": {"type": "boolean", "default": "true", "location": "query"}}, "request": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "response": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}, "list": {"id": "drive.permissions.list", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions", "httpMethod": "GET", "parameters": {"fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}}, "response": {"$ref": "PermissionList"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]}, "patch": {"id": "drive.permissions.patch", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions/{permissionId}", "httpMethod": "PATCH", "parameters": {"fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "permissionId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "transferOwnership": {"type": "boolean", "default": "false", "location": "query"}}, "request": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "response": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}, "update": {"id": "drive.permissions.update", "path": "files/{fileId}/permissions/{permissionId}", "httpMethod": "PUT", "parameters": {"fileId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "permissionId": {"type": "string", "required": true, "location": "path"}, "transferOwnership": {"type": "boolean", "default": "false", "location": "query"}}, "request": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "response": {"$ref": "Permission"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}}}', true));
```

UPDATE:  It looks like this is supported in the new version of the API client (1.0) https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client